# Folder convention in Google drive

Tags: google-drive

What folder this indicates in drive

One with little white dot (shown in image with green color box)

and

other without dot (shown in image with brown color box)

[image]

Comment: That's a person icon; the head and the shoulders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folders that contain the "dots" are those the folders have been shared with other people. On the other hand, folders that do not contain the "dots" are all private only to you..